# Where can I find dataset for product characteristics and its possible values?

Tags: data-request

### The thing is, i need a set of predifined values and characteristics for products, if there will be a category if possible. So I need to have a list of predefined values for my application.

When user will create or edit product, he/she should choose characteristics from ready list of possible characteristics/values/categories. And system will store id's of those characteristics for each product.

Something like:

Characteristic:Color, Value:Red;

Characteristic:Color, Value:Black;

Characteristic:Color, Value:Green;

Characteristic:Material, Value:Metal;

Characteristic:RAM, Value:2GB;

Characteristic:RAM, Value:4GB;

Comment: The example you give is so arbitrary, you should look at *test data generators*. Or explain to us what kind of products and why you need this.